# Positive single-word adjective for "second best"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am giving myself a performance review and I want to say that I am assigning myself the second best rating possible (as we all know that picking the top choice will lead to eye-rolling).

Simply stating "I have chosen to give myself the second-best possible score" doesn't show the regard that I have for that ranking. Second-best often has a negative connotation, and I do not wish to make that connection.

I want a word that is strictly ordinal along the lines of "the penultimate ranking" but as our rankings go from best to worst, I believe penultimate will imply that I am choosing the second-worst ranking.

Comment: How about the horse racing term "place"?  Win-place-show.

Comment: You could just refer to that rating by its name or number ("above average", "4", whatever term is used at your organisation). Whoever will be reading your statement already knows what the possible ratings are.

Comment: I think any word that specifies the place (second) will bring in some negative connotation. I would suggest using a word that reflects the tier of score: "I have chosen to give myself a high score..."

Comment: Second-highest.

Comment: "I have chosen to call myself runner-up."

Comment: Does your rating system have names for each level? I suggest you just use the name, and not worry about this positional system. If not, you could make up a term, like "near-best".

Comment: I like “second-highest” here (as suggest by RegDwight) as it does address any negative connotations. Regarding your last paragraph, I don’t agree that penultimate suggests “second-worst”. “Ultimate” carries with it a strong sense of the best or greatest and this makes your reading of “penultimate” unlikely.

Comment: Second-best; secondbest...I am not getting anything else...

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Check a dictionary, the meaning of "penultimate" is "second last". Although it shares a root with "ultimate", it doesn't share its sense of being "best".

Comment: @Barmar. Yes, you’re right of course!